# how to reload ng-repeat data using angularjs and asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

How would you pass data code to angularjs variable. its working fine when the page loads. But when I click the button, for filter data. The server side does not load data.

> $scope.studentinformation = <%= studentattendancejson %>

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string Query = "Select * from tblstudent WHERE student_name = 'Adeel'";
 var getstudentattendance = DbAccess.GetResult(Query);

      studentattendancejson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getstudentattendance, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

//Angularjs variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
                $scope.currentPage = 0;
                $scope.pageSize = 100;
                $scope.data = [];
                $scope.q = '';

                $scope.studentinformation = <%= studentattendancejson %>
                $scope.getData = function () {


                    return $filter('filter')($scope.studentinformation, $scope.q)

                }
                $scope.numberOfPages = function () {
                    return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length / $scope.pageSize);
                }


            }]);

            app.filter('startFrom', function () {
                return function (input, start) {
                    start = +start; //parse to int
                    return input.slice(start);
                }
            });

        </script>

 <tr ng-repeat="info in studentinformation| filter:q | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                                                    <td>{{info.student_name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{info.father_name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{info.class_name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{info.attendancedate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                                                    <td ng-if="info.attendanceType == 'Present'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
                                                     <td ng-if="info.attendanceType == 'Absent'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>
                                                     <td ng-if="info.attendanceType == 'Leave'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></td>


                                                </tr>
```

Page load its working fine
[image: Page load its working fine]

Button clicked button event its not show data,  below are result
[image]

Comment: Razor c# is only ran when the request is made so the studentattendancejson will not be changed. I think you need to look into using ajax for getting information from the server.

Comment: What is the error message in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reload ng-repeat when i clicked button asp.net (angularjs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747396/how-to-reload-ng-repeat-when-i-clicked-button-asp-net-angularjs)